# Error in NSString statement, but I don't see it

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Here's the statement:

```
NSString *sqlCmd = @"SELECT COUNT (*) FROM SiteData WHERE SITE_ID = '%@'", txtSiteID.text;
```

The error is: expected semicolon at end of declaration'.  I don't see the problem.

Would appreciate any help I can get on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be:

```
NSString *sqlCmd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT COUNT (*) FROM SiteData WHERE SITE_ID = '%@'", txtSiteID.text];
```

Or

```
NSString *sqlCmd = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SELECT COUNT (*) FROM SiteData WHERE SITE_ID = '%@'", txtSiteID.text]];
```

If you use ARC, you can use either method, otherwise, the first method gives you an autoreleased string, and the second method gives you a string with a retain count of 1 and that you have to release at some point.

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
NSString *sqlCmd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT COUNT (*) FROM SiteData WHERE SITE_ID = '%@'", txtSiteID.text];
```

Answer (score 1):

use stringWithFormat:

```
sqlCmd = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT COUNT (*) FROM SiteData WHERE SITE_ID = '%@'", txtSiteID.text];
```